# Error 404 en enlace permanente

Tags: wordpress

Estoy intentando configurar los enlaces permanentes en modo "nombre de la entrada", pero me da un error 404 al acceder a los diferentes links.
Sin embargo, con los enlaces simples si funciona.

Los permisos de DocumentRoot son apache.apache y tienen permisos de acceso y el contenido de la configuración que tengo es la siguiente:

El fichero de configuración del Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName web
  ServerAlias web

  LogLevel debug
  KeepAliveTimeout 100

  ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_web.blog_log
  CustomLog logs/access_web.blog_log combined
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web/blog

 <Directory "/var/www/html/web/blog">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

El fichero .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

He recreado el fichero htaccess y el problema persiste.
Que puede suceder y que puedo mirar mas?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes la configuración en *Ajustes de los Enlaces Permanentes*? ¿Qué permisos tiene .htaccess?

Comment: -rwxrwx---. 1 apache apache 700 Jan  2 17:00 /var/www/html/web/blog/.htaccess

Comment: La configuración está como "Nombre de la entrada"

Comment: Me hace ruido el subdirectorio *blog*, no debería estar; no se necesita incluso para multisitio con subdirectorio. Cuando cambias la configuración de permalinks ¿se modifica el .htaccess o te pide la actualización manual?  ¿Verificaste si se carga el mod_rewrite?

Comment: si modifico la configuración se modifica el .htaccess. mod_rewrite esta cargado

Comment: Ok, si se actualizó debió haberle quitado blog/ al .htaccess y deben funcionar los permalinks. Toma en cuenta que la configuración que posteaste es para https.

Comment: he tirado un nivel anterior para que se eliminara el /blog de .htaccess y sigue igual.. sale el 404 not found. A nivel de BBDD se puede ver de alguna forma si está afectando alguna redirección?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner cómo tienes la configuración en el panel de Wordpress? Desde ahí puedes confgurar los enlaces permanentes sin tener que meterte con el  `.htaccess`, ya que Wordpress lo configura sólo. Creo que tu error ha sido meterte a trastear al `.htaccess`. Ponlo como lo tenías originalmente y cambia los enlaces permanentes desde el panel de administración de Wordpress.

Comment: a nivel de BBDD se puede ver algo? Estoy realizando un upgrade y cambio de servidor y a ver si ahí hay algo raro

Comment: Es que no entiendo por qué te quieres complicar la vida. Como ya dije, no tenías que modificar el `.htaccess` para esto, ni mucho menos tienes que hurgar en la base de datos. Tenías que cambiar los permalinks desde el panel de Administración de WP, que para eso existe. Prueba a revertir lo que hayas hecho en el `.htaccess` y usa el panel de administración de WP. No te sigas metiendo más profundo, lo único que harás será complicar las cosas. Cambiar los permalinks es algo banal en WP, nada más seleccionas desde el panel qué tipo de permalink quieres y listo. No sigas trasteando por otros lados.